# Convert datetime inside a query

Tags: php, sql

Can you compare a DATETIME to a UNIX timestamp on the fly in a `$query`?

Something like:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM customer_appointments 
           WHERE dealer_id = 12880 
             AND $today < $appt_date";

$today = time()
```

`$appt_date = "2011-09-17 00:00:00"`, is a field from `customer_appointments`.

Can't you compare these two right in the query?

Comment: This is a SQL question, not PHP related.  MySQL, I assume?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
DELETE FROM customer_appointments WHERE dealer_id = 12880 AND $today < UNIX_TIMESTAMP( '$appt_date' );
```

That should work for MySQL (unsure what DB You're using).

Also, I suggest you escape your data to prevent [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) from getting into your database.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though confused how that reference (which has been used before with great approval and demonstrates a valid point) has been praised and not criticized.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways what you're asking can be done. You can use `date(Y-m-d H:i:s)` instead of time, You can convert the appt_date to UNIX_TIMESTAMP inside of MySQL, or you can convert it in PHP using strtotime.

I think you're actually trying to do this though:

```sql
DELETE FROM customer_appointments 
       WHERE dealer_id = 12880 
         -- all appointments before now
         AND NOW() < APPT_DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

Mysql can convert dates from and to unix timestamp with no problem.
However, see no use for the unix timestamp in your question

```
DELETE FROM customer_appointments WHERE dealer_id = 12880 AND NOW() < appt_date
```

looks like a solution.
If not - you have to describe your *task* in words.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FROM_UNIXTIME($today) in the query which will allow you to compare the datetime with the timestamp

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime